# MariaDB 10.6.x Error 4150 (HY000) ER_USER_IS_BLOCKED

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have one Web Application Server working with my Maria DB Version 10.6

It has one main service that connects to the database and some other thread that will use a new session to connect to the database.

This time I set some global variables, one of them is **max_connect_errors**  which I decreased the value to **100** to increase the security.

But after some time, I realized that when I tried to log in to the db using the same account as the service has. It's said that it needs to unblock the user by FLUSH PRIVILEGES. And, when I see the log of the server, the thread that should been executed once a day is blocked by the same error.

> 4150 (HY000): User is blocked because of too many credential errors; unblock with 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES';

So I run the FLUSH PRIVILEGES command using the root. It's working for a while just to come to the same situation, but I'm not sure how much time (It could be less than an hour).

I'm not sure what causes this, and I can't find any post that has the same error message.

I have tried to create the same case by creating a new Maria DB Server in which the **max_connect_errors** value has been set to **1**. Then, I try to connect with the wrong password. but the same thing is not happening.

Can somebody enlighten me?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the errors have just been introduced from version 10.4
https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/error-codes/ER_USER_IS_BLOCKED/

Comment: Note [max_password_errors](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_password_errors) is related to FLUSH PRIVILEGES, FLUSH HOSTS is for max_connect_errors.